# Browse networked computer with Windows Explorer, target computer is not bound to the domain

Tags: windows, networking, active-directory

We have a networked computer on a different subnet (192.168.100., where as I am on a 10.100 ip address).  The target computer is not bound to a domain, unlike our 10.* computers which our bound to `ourdomain`.  I am able to browse, with Windows Explorer, any computer bound to the domain.  However, I am unable to do so with the target computer that is not.

A colleague added his username and password to the target computer, and is able to browse to it just fine (i.e., if his login is normally `\ourdomain\username`, he created a local account on the target computer that is just named `username`, and set it's password to be identical).  I attempted the same trick, but still am unable to browse to the network location.

The computer is most certainly reachable - I can remote-desktop to it just fine.  But I'd like to be able to browse to it with Windows Explorer, e.g. `\\target\d$\`.  Any idea what must be done?

My computer is Windows 7 32bit, target is Windows 2008R2.  My collegue (who has it working), is also on Windows 7, but 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely network discovery is turned off on the target machine along with the firewall identifying the network as a public network. Have him go into the network and sharing center control panel, change the zone of that connection to WORK, and enable network discovery and file sharing on that zone. That should take care of the firewall configuration as well.

Comment: but why would it be working for my colleague, but not me?

Comment: If he on the 10.100 network or the 192.168.100 network with the server?

Comment: We are both on the 10.100, the target was on a 192.168.  But it's working now, if I use IP directly.

Comment: Hrmm, probably some kind of NetBIOS name resolution issue.

Answer (score 0):

So, the target computer actually has multiple IP addresses.  It turns out if I reference the IP directly, instead of using name resolution, it works just fine.

e.g.

```
\\targetname\d$
```

vs.

```
\\192.168.100.123\d$
```